# Discord Bot Logging in Over 1000 Times

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I suspect this is happening due to the code below. It's the only bot of 3 with this code. The code itself hasn't been working 100% of the time when the bot is logged in. It's supposed to give anyone that is live streaming a "streaming" role. Some people it adds the role onto and for others it doesn't.

I'd like help for both issues if possible. Mostly the logging issue since I can't even keep the bot online anymore

The code below shows the entire index.js file. The code talked about above is the "presenceUpdate" section of code.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {prefix, token} = require('./config.json');
const welcomeGif = require('./welcomeGifs.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.username} is online!`);
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', gif => {
    gif = new Discord.Attachment(welcomeGif[Math.floor(Math.random() * welcomeGif.length)]);

    client.channels.get('614134721533968494').send(gif);
});

client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    const guild = newPresence.guild;
    const streamingRole = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '720050658149138444');
  
    if (newPresence.user.bot || newPresence.presence.clientStatus === 'mobile' || oldPresence.presence.status !== newPresence.presence.status) return;
  
    const oldGame = oldPresence.presence.activities ? oldPresence.presence.activities.streaming: false;
    const newGame = newPresence.presence.activities ? newPresence.presence.activities.streaming: false;
  
    if (!oldGame && newGame) {         // Started playing.
      newPresence.roles.add(streamingRole)
        .then(() => console.log(`${streamingRole.name} added to ${newPresence.user.tag}.`))
        .catch(console.error);
    } else if (oldGame && !newGame) {  // Stopped playing.
      newPresence.roles.remove(streamingRole)
        .then(() => console.log(`${streamingRole.name} removed from ${newPresence.user.tag}.`))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
});

// This is the start of the main function when the bot is turned on
client.on('message', message => {

    // The bot will not respond if there is no prefix,
    // the user that typed it was a bot,
    // or if it was not sent from in the server
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;

    // Creates the arguments variable and separates it with a space
    // and creates the command variable
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type !== 'text') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.channel.send('There was an error trying to execute that command!\nCheck the console for details.');
    }
});
// This logs in the bot with the specified token found in config
client.login(token);
```

Comment: What is the log that is popping up ?

Comment: The title. Discord keeps sending me a message telling me the bot is logging in over 1000 times in 24 hours. I tried reaching out to them several times and they haven't answered me in the past week.

Comment: the problem seems to be coming from somewhere else.. do you have any error logs before your bot logs in ?

Comment: No. Everything logs in perfectly fine with no issues. A day later it's offline and when I try to run it again, I get the error that I have the wrong login credentials since they keep changing the token.

Comment: First question : what are you using to host your bot ? 2: I think we will need a more complete version of your code (the more the better) to help us find out what could be causing this

Comment: I'm using a VPS through Vultr. As for the code, I'll edit my question with the full main file.

Comment: everything seems to be fine here :/ I'd suggest you to run some tests locally (not on your vps) and to try every single command you have, to find out what might be wrong here

Comment: You could as well try to add a more powerful error handler to find if there's an error somewhere

Comment: I honestly don't have any commands with that bot just yet. I created the command handler since the person I created the bot for had more ideas to do anyway so I thought I'd start with a command handler to be prepared. The bot didn't have the logging issues until last week and the bot's been running for about a month now. i wish Discord would respond to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm getting closer and closer I think. I think the issue is that upon the bot logging in, it crashes from an error I found. When it crashes it is set to automatically restart so when it restarts it crashes again and repeats the cycle. The error I found is "clientStatus" is undefined which is in the presenceUpdate section.

Comment: Did you fix your issue yet ?

Comment: Kinda not fully. I’m getting error after error every time I change the code. Errors that don’t make sense. Like it’s telling me .activities is undefined but that’s a Discord js v12 thing so I’m not sure how it’s undefined. For now I’m just commenting that whole thing out til I get help